# Help describing a graph for vector valued functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Doing a little summer study and my textbook doesn't have much answers so thought I'd ask here. The topic is an introduction to vector-valued functions

The question asks to 'describe the graph' $\vec r(t)=7 \vec i+ 2 \cos t \ \vec j +2 \sin t\ \vec k$

Would "circular helix in 3-space starting at $(7,2,0)$ that moves in a path by $y(t)=2\cos(t)$ and $z(t)=2\sin(t)$" be sufficient? For these types of questions would I need to give some sort of directional vector?

Answer (score 0):

If your $r(t)$ is correctly written, you don't have an helix, but a circle.

More precisely, the circle having radius equal to $2$ in the plane $x=7$ and whose center lies on $x$-axis.

Comment: Ah thanks silly mistake. "Circle in 3space in the plane x=7" looks much more sensible

Comment: Yes. And to be more precise see my answer edit.